# How to lose weight without doing exercise?

Tags: body-fat, weight-loss

I am a 27 year old working woman. I don't have time to do any workouts or any physical execise. I got married 4 months ago, and since then I am putting on weight very fast. I have done gym work before, around 4 months due to which I lost 4 to 5 kgs (9-11 lbs) before marrige. Is there any way to lose weight without doing any physical workout and without hard core dieting?

Comment: No time to do workouts or any physical exercise? Really? You can't find 1/2 hour a few times per week to do something like take a brisk walk?

Comment: as i see it, the gaining of weight is a symptom of an unhealthy lifestyle, and even if there is a way to loose the extra weight without doing exercise, this might be actually a bad idea. rather try to make your life sane again, because as kind of mentioned by @CareyGregory, if you really can't find a few times 30min of time a week, you have bigger problems then just gaining weight, like stress. for whatever reason you have no time (work, children, ...), remember that if you get more and more sick, you will not be able to be a good partner, parent, employee or whatever.

Comment: I can not believe you guys, many people have answered this question. Hellooo, he wants to sit and eat and lose weight. What are we talking about. What have we been discussing  here? Let's get serious. There is nothing like no diet, sit and lose weight. The body does not work that way. You have to exercise and eat healthy to lose weight and not gain back.

Answer (score 6):

Besides changing the amount of calories you expend or consume there aren't many more options. You might attempt to reduce your stress level. The 1994 paper [Stress-induced cortisol response and fat distribution in women](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16353426) and the 2000 paper [Stress and Body Shape: Stress-Induced Cortisol Secretion Is Consistently Greater Among Women With Central Fat](http://journals.lww.com/psychosomaticmedicine/Abstract/2000/09000/Stress_and_Body_Shape__Stress_Induced_Cortisol.5.aspx) indicated a possible link between elevated cortisol (sometimes called the stress hormone, although that is far from the whole story) and increased abdominal fat distribution. Of course, you may find stress regulation as or even more difficult than finding time to exercise.

However - diet and exercise remains the preferred method of weight loss. Particularly compared to the risks of medication or surgery. Any way you slice it, it takes behavioral changes to make physical changes. Exercise can be a great way to reduce stress, too.

Answer (score 3):

Losing weight via means of altering your diet will be safest choice, however, that doesn't mean it is your only option. In my opinion, *dieting* is an incredibly vague term. Ensuring you are eating a balanced diet and eating within your daily needs is better way to put it.

When you consume an excess of calories that your body doesn't need it often stores this fat independently, for future use i.e. as an energy source. [Fat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_fat), despite the bad rep, [is a very good energy source](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6778757) and is essential in our diets - more specifically in times of (unintentional?) fasting. Is it healthy to use fat as a stable for your energy needs? No. It's all about maintaining a justified ratio of Carbohydrates; fats and proteins that build a stable foundation for a diet.

Consider this when contemplating a weight loss diet: 'In 2005, the “American Journal of Clinical Nutrition” published the results of a study in which subjects who ate [30% protein, 20% fats and 50% carbohydrates](http://www.livestrong.com/article/303969-the-protein-fat-and-carbohydrate-ratio-for-losing-weight/) felt fuller and ate an average of more than 400 fewer calories daily when compared to subjects who ate a diet of 15% protein, 35% fats and 50% carbohydrates.

The most abundant method for weight loss that is clinically proven, would be obtaining a prescription for [*Orlistat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlistat), aka Alli. Additionally, you will only be able to obtain this medicine if you are truly overweight and if you are have "fair" reasoning etc.

[Orlistat](http://www.webmd.boots.com/diet/guide/medicine-for-obesity) belongs to drug class called *Lipase inhibitors*. Lipase is the in situ enzyme that breaks down lipids (fats), so that they can effectively be absorbed by our body, and hence inhibiting this enzyme allows most of the fat we consume to pass through our digestive system, to be release via excretion in our fecal matter. It would be fair to say that this treatment is in favor of resisting storage/absorption some types of fat more than others. In this case it's [visceral fat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adipose_tissue#Obesity) - fat stored in the abdominal cavity and hence around our major organs. Knowing this, you should be able to comprehend how a physician may deem you suitable for a prescription. If he/she concludes that you are overweight and predisposed to risk of diseases such as cardiovascular disease, the decision will tilt in your favor.

Edit: Orlistat is the generic name for the "weight loss" aid not sold over-the- counter. Alli, is [orlistat](http://www.webmd.boots.com/diet/guide/medicine-for-obesity) at half its dosage and is sold over-the-counter.

Comment: It is incredibly refreshing to see references in an answer. Great job! Please do have a look at our meta, though; you will see guidelines on [reliable references](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112/169) and other valuable material. Thanks, and welcome!